# Let promise stay unresolved until button click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I currently got something like this:

```
var promise = $interval(function(){
                        if(scope.state.showDialog === false){
                            console.log("Done");
                            $interval.cancel(promise);
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            console.log("Not canceled");
                        }
                    },200);
                    return promise;
```

What I want to acheive is a the interval-promise being resolved after a button is pressed so I can chain it further. I'm trying to make a chainable dialog, but I think I've painted myself into a corned with this approach, as it seems like I need to add count in order for the interval to resolve.

So, how am I able to hold a promise until a button is clicked? I'm stumped.

Comment: use `promise.resolve` and `promise.reject`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working for an angular promise

Comment: Will write a new anwser, as `$interval` already returns a promise;

Comment: Just put `resolve` of a `new Promise` as the click handler of the dialog. Unfortunately you didn't share that code. Using an interval for polling the `showDialog` state is not the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return promise;` will never be returned.

You can't return a `value` *outside* of a `function`.

The `promise` should look like this:

```
scope.promise = function ()
{
    var promise = $interval(function ()
    {
        if (scope.state.showDialog === false)
        {
            console.log("Done");

            return true;
        }
    }, 200);

    return promise;
}
```

Then use it like this to activate the `$interval`:

```
scope.promise();
```

**Demo snippet**

```js
angular.module("app", [])

.controller("myController", function($scope, $interval, $timeout) {
  $scope.state = {};
  $scope.state.showDialog = true;

  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.state.showDialog = false;
  }, 2000)

  $scope.promise = function ()
  {
      var promise = $interval(function ()
      {
          if ($scope.state.showDialog === false)
          {
              console.log("Done");
              $interval.cancel(promise);
              
              return $scope.state.showDialog;
          }
          else 
          {
            console.log("False")
          
            return false;
          }
      }, 200);

      return promise;
  }
  
  $scope.promise();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="myController"></div>
</div>
```

**Demo snippet with resolved promise**

`$interval` requires to resolve the promise manually.

```js
angular.module("app", [])

.controller("myController", function($scope, $interval, $timeout, $q) {
  $scope.state = {};
  $scope.state.showDialog = true;

  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.state.showDialog = false;
  }, 2000)

  $scope.promise = function ()
  {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
  
      var promise = $interval(function ()
      {
          if ($scope.state.showDialog === false)
          {
              console.log("Done");
              $interval.cancel(promise);
              
              deferred.resolve($scope.state.showDialog);
          }
          else 
          {
            console.log("False")
          }
      }, 200);

      return deferred.promise;
  }
  
  $scope.promise().then(function(response) {
    console.log("Promised has been resolved");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="myController"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to let me chain to the promise. No debugger hitting or console printing anything

Comment: I added a demo, see snippet.